# Finding parity check matrix from linear code definition

Tags: coding-theory

Say we know the definition of a general linear code over a prime field. It could be something like this for example:

$$C = \{ x_1x_2\ldots x_n | x_i \in \mathbb{F}_q, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^q \equiv 0 \pmod{q}\} $$

Is there a way to derive its parity check matrix from this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific example, since $x^q=x,$ for all $x\in F_q,$ your defining equation is equivalent to $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\equiv 0 \mod  q$$

This defines a linear code.

More generally applying a Groebner basis algorithm to the defining equations will give you a generating set.

Comment: Should be mod q not mod 5, sorry, gonna fix it.

Comment: Or do you  just mean the operation is in $F_q$? Unless $q$ is prime the teo are not the same.

Comment: q is definitely prime, your solution works - I was just trying to generalize it. Sorry for the confusion.